# how to get a single element from an array by comparing with a string value in xcode?

Tags: objective-c

how to get a single element from an array by comparing with a string value.I have a string in a textfield.I want to compare that textfield string with an array.And i want to get that single element form that array.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an `NSArray` of `NSString`'s and you just want to see whether or not the text field string is in the array you can use:

```
NSString *textFieldString;   // Contents of my text field
NSArray *myArray;            // Array to search
BOOL stringMatches = [myArray containsObject:textFieldString];
```

If you instead want to know the index of the string in the array use:

```
NSUInteger index = [myArray indexOfObject:textFieldString];
```

If `index == NSNotFound` the array does not contain the text field string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `compare:` method.

```
for (int i=0; i<[yourArray count]; i++) {
    NSString * string = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([textfield.text compare:string]) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        break;
    }
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use isEqualToString: method for campare two String.

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSString * string = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    i if (string isEqualToString:textField.text)
    {       
      NSLog(@"Equal");        
    }
    else
    {
      NSLog(@"Not Equal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
for (NSString * string in yourArray) {
    if ([string isEqualToString:textField.text])
    {       
      NSLog(@" They are equal");        
    }
    else
    {
      NSLog(@" They are not");
    }
}
```